# how can I reloade a tree in extjs when click on a button

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a button which calculate some items in my TreeStore. When I click on it I want to reload my tree. But now when I click on an item to calculate it, create another tree like same one under selected item and then reload new one. How can I write appropriate code for this problem?

This is my function when click on calculate button:

```
'g-infitmformula #calculateFormula': {
            click: function (sender) {
                var selectedinfoIdList = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("g-infitmformula")[0].getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                Ext.each(selectedinfoIdList, function (item) {
                    informationItemIds.push(item.data.id);
                });
                if (selectedinfoIdList.length > 0) {
                    Dufo.Func.loadMask(Ext.getBody(), true);
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: '/sis/rest/infoit/calculateFormula',
                        jsonData: {
                            infoItemStrings: informationItemIds
                        },
                        success: function (result, request) {
                            var data = Ext.JSON.decode(result.responseText).ReturnValue;
                            Ext.Msg.alert('', data.description);
                            Dufo.Func.loadMask(Ext.getBody(), false);
                            if (data.successful === true) {
                                // Ext.ComponentQuery.query('g-infitmformula')[0].store.reload();
                                Ext.ComponentQuery.query("g-infitmformula")[0].store.reload({
                                    params: {
                                        id: "root",
                                        dtstart: dtstartVar,
                                        dtend: dtendVar,
                                        infitmcat: infitmcatVar
                                    }
                                });
                                informationItemIds = [];
                            }
                            else {
                                informationItemIds = [];
                                Ext.Msg.alert('', data.description);
                            }
                        },
                        failure: function (result, request) {
                            Dufo.Func.loadMask(Ext.getBody(), false);
                            informationItemIds = [];
                            Ext.Msg.alert('', Ext.JSON.decode(result.responseText).ReturnValue.description || Dufo.ux.fa.jsonFormatFail);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('', Dufo.ux.fa.selectSomething);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my store class which I want to reload:

```
Ext.define('Dufo.store.InformationItemsFormula', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
  storeId: 'infitmformula',
  model: 'Dufo.model.InformationItemsFormula',
  autoLoad: false,
  nodeParam: 'id',
  clearOnLoad: true,
  listeners: {
    append: function (parent, child, index, eOpts) {
        var me = this;
        if (!child.isRoot()) {
            child.set('leaf', child.get('isLeaf'));
            if (child.data.children) {
                var root = me.tree.treeStore.getRootNode();
                child.data.children.forEach(function (test) {
                    var n = root.createNode(test);
                    child.appendChild(n);
                });
            }
        }
    }
  },

  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/sis/rest/infitmval/gtinffmlitmval',
    actionMethods: {
        read: 'POST', create: 'POST'
    },
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    jsonData: true,
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: function (o) {


            if (o.ReturnValue) {
                if(o.ReturnValue.detail.length) {
                    Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#calculateFormula")[0].setDisabled(false);
                }else {
                    Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#calculateFormula")[0].setDisabled(true);
                }

                for (var i=0; i < o.ReturnValue.detail.length; i++) {
                    o.ReturnValue.detail[i].id = o.ReturnValue.detail[i].id + '-' +Dufo.store.TreeStoreIDGenerator.generateId();
                }

                return o.ReturnValue.detail;
            }
        }
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You below code is creating issue because you are explicitly create same node. Those node will be also created by Extjs it self.

```
listeners: {
    append: function (parent, child, index, eOpts) {
        var me = this;
        if (!child.isRoot()) {
            child.set('leaf', child.get('isLeaf'));
            if (child.data.children) {
                var root = me.tree.treeStore.getRootNode();
                child.data.children.forEach(function (test) {
                    var n = root.createNode(test);
                    child.appendChild(n);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Remove this code because `append` listeners can be use to perform some operation no newly created node. This is basically call from `Called from a node's appendChild method`.

Comment: I removed it but it doesn't work. It create another tree under my selected item again.

Comment: Please provide fiddle if possible.